# How to sum two different group by calculated fields in Tableau?

Tags: group-by, sum, tableau-api

[image]I have two calculated fields (HomeScore, AwayScore) and I grouped them by different dimensions(Home, Away). Now, I have TotalRuns per Team both in HomeGames and AwayGames. My problem is that I want to find the sum of TotalRuns per Team not separetely for home games and away games. I want to add  these group-by fields somehow. I attach a screenshot to see my work. For example first column for both charts is "Arizona Diamondbacks" which has 263 Runs in first chart and 337 in the second one. I want to show the 263+337=600 Runs. Any Idea?

Comment: Create a new Calculated Field called `Total Runs (Home + Away) = HomeScore + AwayScore`, then make a bar chart using this new calculated field as your measure, then drop Home/Away on the color shelf for a stacked bar chart with Home and Away runs as different colors?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a [LOD expression](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm).

```
{FIXED [Team Name] : SUM([Total Runs])}
```

Think of your data as a big table (which it technically always is in Tableau). Every grouping, filter, etc. that you do narrows down the number of columns and rows you have left until you are left with your data set that contributes to your chart. LOD expressions allow you to back out of the filters, etc. in your calculation. In this case, you narrowed down to home or away games, and we are backing out of that to get a bigger picture of the data.

Comment: I have not dimension "Team Name", all I have is two dimensions Home and Away so How can I create this LOD expression? if I use home or away, the graph it is not show me the right result.

Comment: Instead of team name, use the dimension that holds the team names. It's the dimension that's under Columns on your charts.

Comment: Yes that's the problem in my charts it is not the same dimension. In the left one is the "Home" Dimension and in the right is the "Away" Dimension.  I do not have one for all of them. When I select one of them the results it is not the expectable.

Comment: Whatever the dimension with the values "Boston Red Sox", "Atlanta Braves", etc. is the one we're looking for. You have a dimension and a measure. The Dimension is the name of the team, the measure is probably the Home/Away scores

Comment: With this LOD expression the output is not the TotalRuns that each team has scored but the TotalRuns which have been scored in home games (or away games) both in offence and defense. I want the offense of each team both in home and away.